# Use ajax on client side when working with node

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a very basic nodejs app that is displaying a html pages. This pages has two buttons linked with js function in a separated file. One of the function use ajax, the other not. The one using ajax is not working (not found I guess).
The external js file was working perfectly well under apache. Is there something specific to do to be able to use ajax on client side with node.js?

Here the node.js part:

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express ();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/CSS'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/font'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/ChemAlive_JS'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.sendFile('/home/laetitia/Project/ChemAlive_Interface_Node/test.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

The html part:

```
<html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="/Interface.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/ketcher.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/font-chemalive.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ddsmoothmenu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=/ddsmoothmenu-v.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ui_bis.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="background">
      <div id="LoginButton" class="deck login" &nbsp;>
      <img class="LoginButtonUnpressed" alt="Login/Start" src="/ChemAlive_Start_Button.png">
      <img class="LoginButtonPressed" alt="Login/Start" src="/ChemAlive_Start_Button_pressed.png">
      <div class="popup" style="top: 0px; right: 80px;">
        <p>Log-on or launch your calculations.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Welcome Dialogue box -->
    <div id="welcome_DB" class="dialogWindow fileDialog" >
      <div class="h1">
        <p>Welcome. Thank you for visiting our interface!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="iconDiv">
        <img src="/Green_gears.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="desText">
          <p>ChemAlive i</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navDiv">
        <input type="submit" id="welcome_cancel" class="dialogButton" value="Cancel"/>
        <label for="welcome_cancel" onclick="gototry();"><span class="label">Just Try It</span></label>
        <input id="welcome_login" class="dialogButton" type="submit" value="Done"/>
        <label for="welcome_login" style="right: 10px" onclick="gotologin();"><span class="label">Login</span></label>
        <input id="welcome_register" class="dialogButton" type="submit" value="Done"/>
        <label for="welcome_register" style="right: 20px" onclick="gotoregister();" ><span class="label">Registration</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Close welcome DB -->
    </div>     
  </body>
</html>
```

And the external, client side, js:

```
$('LoginButton').observe('click', ui.onClick_login);
ui.onClick_login = function() {
    window.alert("Hey There")
    ui.showDialog('register_login');
}

function gototry() {
    document.getElementById("welcome_DB").style.display = "none";
}

function gotologin() {
    document.getElementById("welcome_DB").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_v2").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function gotoregister() {
    document.getElementById("welcome_DB").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("register_DB").style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Its `$('LoginButton').observe('click', ui.onClick_login)` call is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#LoginButton')` instead of `$('LoginButton')`?

Comment: @KRONWALLED just tried, it's not changing anything.

Comment: For a simple onClick you can use `$('#LoginButton').on('click', ui.onClick_login);`

Comment: Which is your external client side js file ?? just name it ? And then please check the page source on a browser to make sure that the path is correct

Comment: @KRONWALLED not working better

Comment: @SherinJose The non jquery request in this file are fine so  guess the path is correct

Comment: can you rename ui.onClick_login to a simple name like my_onclick_login

Comment: Then you just give an `alert()` only in that external file. Do you get that one ?

Comment: Do what @enRaiser said. `jQuery.Deferred exception: ui is not defined ReferenceError: ui is not defined` - See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frha8x1m/) or define the `ui` namespace like here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frha8x1m/1/)

Comment: You're right thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename ui.onClick_login to a simple name like my_onclick_login

```
$('#LoginButton').observe('click', my_onclick_login);
    my_onclick_login = function() {
    window.alert("Hey There")
    ui.showDialog('register_login');
}
```